# Direct / Executor Channel - bypass some custom exception in case of failover strategy set to true ( don`t use other subscribers )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

Is there a possibility to bypass failover strategy in Direct Channel when custom Exceptions is thrown ?

If I add custom Error Channel - error message will reach error channel after all subscribers will be exhausted( in my case all JmsOutboundGateway will fail).

In my case I would like to check what error was the first error in **inputLocalChannel** ( in my case in jmsOutboundGateway) and if its expected error then stop processing (failover flow - don't pass it to other subscriber) and throw error - pass it to callback -> on Error

---

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "LocalGateway" , errorChannel = "defaultErrorChannel")
public interface LocalGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    ListenableFuture<Message<String>> sendMsg(Message<String> request);

}
```

---

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow someFlow() {
        return f -> f
                .routeByException(r -> r
                        .channelMapping(MessageTimeoutException.class, "customErrorChannel")
                        .defaultOutputChannel("defaultErrorChannel"));
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel defaultErrorChannel() {

        DirectChannel dr = new DirectChannel();
        return dr;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel customErrorChannel() {

        DirectChannel dr = new DirectChannel();
        return dr;
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "defaultErrorChannel")
    private void processDefaultError(ErrorMessage errMsg)  {
            throw errMsg.getPayload();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "customErrorChannel")
    private void processCustomError(ErrorMessage errMsg) {

      // some code 

    }
```

---

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    public Message<String>firstHandler(){
    // some code
}

@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    public Message<String> secondHandler(){
    // some code
}


@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputGateway")
    public JmsOutboundGateway firstGateway(){
    // some code
}

@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputGatewayBck")
    public JmsOutboundGateway secondGateway(){
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something what can be called as a "conditional failover".

That feature is indeed not available for `DirectChannel`, and  I don't it has to be.

I suggest yo look into an `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/router/implementations.html#router-implementations-exception-router. This way you would need to have more channels, include the `errorChannel` option of the `@MessagingGateway`. So, when error happens on the first gateway, you handle it by that `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter` and decide where to go next.

**UPDATE**

This is what I thought about your "conditional failover":

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "LocalGateway" , errorChannel = "routeErrorChannel")
public interface LocalGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    ListenableFuture<Message<String>> sendMsg(Message<String> request);

}


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("routeErrorChannel")
                .routeByException(r -> r
                        .channelMapping(MessageTimeoutException.class, "secondInputLocalChannel")
                        .defaultOutputChannel("rethrowErrorChannel"));
    }

@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
    public Message<String>firstHandler(){
    // some code
}

@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "secondInputLocalChannel")
    public Message<String> secondHandler(){
    // some code
}
```

So, you catch an error from the `inputLocalChannel` in that `routeErrorChannel`. And there with the `routeByException()` you make a decision according to the exception your got. In my example you send the message into a `secondInputLocalChannel` when `MessageTimeoutException`. However you still need to unwrap a `failedMessage` from that exception before publishing it into that `secondInputLocalChannel`. Otherwise the whole `ErrorMessage` is going to be sent. See `MessagingException.getFailedMessage()` property.

Comment: I updated the code. I have added error channels and integration flow to map errors.  But  still while "inputGateway" firstGateway is failing with  MessageTimeoutException - error is not handled by customErrorChannel but there is retry on second subscriber and error goes to  defaultErrorChannel. How can I route/handle error thrown in inputGateway and pass it to custom error handler ?

Comment: I tried to change Integration flow for error mappings with:
    @Bean
    public ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter(MessageChannel defaultErrorChannel) {
        ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter router = new ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter();
        Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
        mappings.put(MessageTimeoutException.class.getName(), "customErrorChannel");
        router.setChannelMappings(mappings);
        router.setDefaultOutputChannel(defaultErrorChannel);
        return router;
    }

but it didnt helped

Comment: error thrown by input gateway:
**dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher** ->  An exception was thrown by 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@3ccdf1] (ncoreOutboundGatewayMqConfig.takeOverControlSecond.serviceActivator)' while handling 'GenericMessage [payload=sdsadas_0_, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@148d352, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@148d352, id=* timestamp=*}]'. Failing over to the next subscriber.

Comment: org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 1000ms

Comment: With the router solution you must not have two subscribers for the first channel. The second subscriber must use its own channel. And you send there only after the router logic.

Comment: Then I will lose load balancing between those two subscribers - in my case those two gateways have same logic but they are connected to different servers. In case of MessageTimeout I don't want any retries.  Maybe I didn't understand it correctly.  ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter  will work only when there is 1 subscriber ?  So whole flow from @Gateway to last channel used in chain should have only 1 subscriber ?

Comment: even if I deleted second subscriber IntegrationFlow  with error mapping doesn't work - in all cases it goes to default error channel  - should I add something exrta to enable  ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter ?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Hope that makes things clear.

Comment: now its clear for me. Thanks :)  but I was thinking about something else - I want to have two JmsOutboundGateways connected to one channel( to have load balancing).  
 In case of MessageTimeoutException in first attempt in gateway I want to stop the flow and do not pass message to second subscriber( process it) but push message straight to errorChannel.  
In You're code there will be no load balancing and **secondInputLocalChannel** will be backup gateway if MessageTimeoutException occurs in first attempt.
  Is there any way to skip second subscriber if first one is failing with exception?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean with this `routeByException()`: there is just not conditional `failover` on the `DirectChannel`.

Comment: `failover = false`, but then what is the purpose of two subscribers for the same channel?

Comment: For load balancing. Those two JmsOutboundGateway are connected to different servers but inside they have same logic. Due to small timeouts - if request fails with MessageTimeoutException I don't want to use second/backup Jmsoutboundgateway. But if 
for example mq connection for  one of JmsOutboundGateway is down then i want to try to process request on another Jmsoutboundgateway.

Comment: Right. That's conditional, therefore router. Well, we probably can introduce a simple `Predicate<Exception> failoverStrategy` into `DirectChannel` and its `UnicastingDispatcher`. So, if it is `true`, we go to the next subscriber, if not throw an exception upstream. Feel free to raise respective GH issue with clarification and reasoning. Thanks